# css Max-Width won't resize image

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a flexible grid website and I ran into a snag. It doesn't appear that the CSS property `max-width:100%;` is working on my logo image. It's supposed to resize along with the flexible grid, but it's not. Maybe I'm not calling the image correctly or my syntax is incorrect? The image is 200x67, and here's the relevant HTML:

```
<header>
<img src="images/so_200.png" alt="Website.com" id="logo" />
</header>
```

and here's the CSS for that:

```
header {
background-color:#ccc;
padding:1%;
}
img #logo {
display: block;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

Any idea why it's not working? It shouldn't matter the image is a .png, right?

Comment: Remove space between img and #logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space between the id and element:

img #logo => img#logo

```
img#logo {
  display: block;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove space between `img` and `#logo`

```
img#logo {
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Image file type(png) doesn't matter for css rules.

Comment: right answer and one more thing!!.we cant see any changes here,But the changes are already done..decrease `max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;` values something like `max-width:20%;' and see the changes